# IntlDateFormatter is wrong from 00h00 to 00h59

Tags: php, date, timezone

The following code display "5 octobre 2012" (that is correct) except when i execute it from 00h00 to 00h59. Instead, the output is "6 octobre 2012"...

I'm french and live in Paris. I can't understand why there is a variation and how to correct it.
Thx for helping me.

```
$formatterDMY=new IntlDateFormatter('fr_FR',IntlDateFormatter::LONG,IntlDateFormatter::NONE,'Europe/Paris',IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN );
$aDate=new DateTime();
$aDate->setDate(2012, 10, 5);
echo $formatterDMY->format($aDate);
```

Comment: "except when i execute it from" --- what happens then? Do we need to move to France and wait until midnight to realize that?

Comment: Is your timezone (set in php.ini) and time correct?

Comment: indeed ^^i edit my question

Comment: The timezone in php.ini was "UTC" i replace it by "Europe/Paris" and now it's ok :) Thanks Zerkms !